# Numpy reshape/dimension change

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change an array such as

```
array([[  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.],
       [  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.],
       [  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.],
       [  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.]])
```

To

```
array([[[7.,   3.],
        [7.,   3.],
        [7.,   3.],
        [7.,   3.]],

       [[14.,   1.],
        [14.,   1.],
        [14.,   1.],
        [14.,   1.]],

       [[9.,   17.],
        [9.,    17.],
        [9.,   17.],
        [9.,   17.]]])
```

I thought I would manage with reshape, but none of the order statements work in this case. Currently, I am doing it this way

```
np.vstack([mat[:, i-2:i] for i in range(2, mat.shape[1]+1, 2)]).reshape(3,-1,2)
```

And I was wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: `mat.reshape(4, 3, 2).swapaxes(0, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reshape` and then `swapaxes`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
      [[  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.],
       [  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.],
       [  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.],
       [  7.,   3.,  14.,   1.,   9.,  17.]])

a.reshape((a.shape[0], -1, 2)).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you